# Codificacion SHA1 en C#

Tags: c#, codificación

Necesito codificar una contraseña y guardarla en `SQL`, para la parte de guardarla no tengo problema, pero con la parte del cifrado no se que hacer. (Nunca he hecho algo similar)

Tengo el siguiente código que encontré en un foro:

```
public class Program
{
    public static string encriptar(string Cadena)
    {              
            SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] vectoBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Cadena);
            byte[] inArray = SHA1.ComputeHash(vectoBytes);
            SHA1.Clear();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);            
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(encriptar("Hola Mundo"));
    }
}
```

Pero no lo entiendo muy bien, ¿Alguien me puede explicar su funcionamiento?

También me gustaría saber si es posible revertir el proceso de encriptación, es decir, tomar la cadena resultante y obtener la contraseña.

Comment: Cual es la parte que no entendes? y solamente algunos tipos de cifrado son reversibles, y no te los recomiendo, justamente porque son reversibles...

Comment: para claves no es recomendable usar un reversible. no necesitas saber la contraseña, sólo necesitas saber que es igual. hash de lo que te dan = hash de lo que tenes guardado -> ok

Comment: Hola, a modo de anécdota, qué gestor de Base de Datos usas? Usas SQL Server? Si es asi, éste tiene funciones para cifrar contraseñas. [HASHBYTES](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te lo explico lo mejor que pueda. Parto de la base de que el método encriptar es el que no comprendes.

```
public static string encriptar(string Cadena)
{              
        SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] vectoBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Cadena);
        byte[] inArray = SHA1.ComputeHash(vectoBytes);
        SHA1.Clear();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);            
}
```

Pues nada, vamos paso a paso. Es un método que recibe la cadena que quieres transformar (en este caso será tu contraseña) y devuelve el resultado de aplicar la función resumen (que en este caso será SHA1) a la contraseña.

Bien, entrando en el método:

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider SHA1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
```

Esta línea crea una instancia de tipo SHA1CryptoServiceProvider. SHA1CryptoServiceProvider es la clase que contiene la función SHA1. Esta función se llama "ComputeHash". Requiere un array de bytes a transformar y devuelve otro array de bytes con la transformación.

Aunque esto es solo mi opinión, la instancia opera con bytes por comodidad, por eficiencia y porque aspectos de las cadenas de texto como la codificación no tienen nada que ver con el problema a abordar (las cadenas de texto de .Net tiene codificación Unicode)

Como la función necesita un array de bytes, tendremos que conseguir el array de bytes de la cadena de texto.

```
byte[] vectoBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Cadena);
```

Si Cadena tomara el valor "Boss", vectoBytes tomaría el valor de un array con cuatro valores: [0x42, 0x6F, 0x73 0x73]

B -> 0x42
O -> 0x6F
S -> 0x73
S -> 0x73

Ahora disponemos de nuestra contraseña en el tipo deseado (byte[]), así que ya podemos generar el hash:

```
byte[] inArray = SHA1.ComputeHash(vectoBytes);
```

A continuación, vamos a liberar los recursos que ha utilizado SHA1.

.Net administra la memoria RAM que utilizamos durante la ejecución de un programa, pero existen dos problemas fundamentales:

1. Esta gestión no es perfecta ni eficiente (no voy a entrar en detalles, creo que mi respuesta ya es lo suficientemente extensa).
2. .Net no puede gestionar la memoria que se ha reservado de forma independiente al gestor de memoria de .Net (memoria no administrada, tampoco entraré en detalles).

Por estos dos motivos ciertos objetos tienen código que libera los recursos que el administrador de memoria no puede liberar, ya sea por el motivo 1, el 2 u otro que se me haya escapado.

```
SHA1.Clear();
```

Bien, finalmente devolvemos los resultados.

Como dije antes, la función ComputeHash devuelve un array de bytes. Como nuestro método debe devolver una cadena de texto, generamos una cadena de texto equivalente a la collección de bytes. esta vez se elige transformar los Bytes a Base64, entiendo que esto se debe a que así se minimizan los problemas relacionados con la codificación a costa de incrementar la longitud de la cadena de texto (sí, Base 64 multiplica el número de caracteres en un factor de hasta 4/3).

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
```

Ésto es todo, espero que os sea de utilidad.